# Tensor of ring of formal power series and a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, formal-power-series

Let $L/K$ be (any) field extension. Is it true that we have an isomorphism $K[[t_1, \dots, t_n]] \otimes L \cong L[[t_1, \dots, t_n]]$?

We know that if we remove the field assumption, this is not true. Take, for example, $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$.

On the other hand, if the extension is a finite field extension this is true since then
$L$ would be a free $K$ module of finite rank. (If I am not mistaken, by taking the direct limit over all finite extension, we can also show that this is true if $L/K$ is algebraic).

Comment: Hint: Show that the image of the canonical tensor product map lands in the space of formal power series $f$ such that there is a sub-$K$-algebra $M$ of $L$, finitely generated over $K$, containing all the coefficients of $f$.

Comment: Anything unclear?

Comment: When you say, "is it true that we have an isomorphism $K[[t_1, \ldots, t_n]] \otimes L \cong L[[t_1, \ldots, t_n]]$, do you mean to ask if the *canonical* multiplication map from the former ring to the latter is an isomorphism? Or are you wondering (as the question now reads) if any isomorphism is possible?

Comment: @BadamBaplan I would expect the canonical map to do the job, but even a non canonical map would do.

Comment: Although I think I was able to solve it with @Aphelli 's Instructions.

Comment: @SergetheToaster you should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @ronno The proof I wrote was basically a less organised version of what reuns added below....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the canonical map:
$$A=K[[t_1,\ldots,t_n]]\otimes_K L$$ is the subring of $B=L[[t_1,\ldots,t_n]]$ of formal power series whose coefficients lie in a finite dimensional $K$-vector subspace of $L$.

So $A$ is the whole of $B$ iff $L/K$ is a finite extension.

---

For a possible non-canonical isomorphism:

Both $A$ and $B$ are local rings (their non-units form a maximal ideal) and $B$ is complete $\cong\varprojlim_{k\to \infty} B/\mathfrak{m}_B^k$.

But $A$ is non-complete if $L/K$ is not a finite extension (if $\ell_j$ is a $K$-linearly independent sequence of elements of $L$ then $\sum_{j\ge 0} t_1^j\otimes \ell_j $ is in the completion $\varprojlim_{k\to \infty} A/\mathfrak{m}_A^k$  but not in $A$)

So $A$ and $B$ are not isomorphic as abstract rings.

Comment: +1, This shows that the default map is not an isomorphism.